# Checking the return value of $.get with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Prevent a submission of a form via POST and submit once conditions are met. 
Form is being submitted, I am not sure how to check if the function (which passes an HTML input into Python that checks a database if the user exists (Returns in JSON format true if it doesn't and false if it exists).

I have tried checking if the function is true, which for most cases work, I wonder if it is the $.get is an odd case?

```
document.getElementById("register").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let input = document.getElementsByName("username");
        function(check) {
            $.get('/check?username=' + input.value, function(data) {
                document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = data;
            })
        if (check()) {
                this.submit();
            }
        else {
            alert ("username is taken!");
            return false;
        }


@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
    # Check the http parameter for username.
    username = request.args.get("username")

    check = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=username)

    if not check:
        return jsonify(True)
    else:
        return jsonify(False)
```

I want the alert to flash and prevent form submission of the function runs and returns json(False) - which would indicate the username is taken

But right now it is submitting the form.

Comment: aside: just do `return jsonify(not check)` and avoid the if/else construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.get()` is asynchronous so you can't return a value from `check()`

Instead do the submit inside `$.get()` callback if response is true

```
document.getElementById("register").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let input = document.getElementsByName("username")[0];

  $.getJSON('/check?username=' + input.value, function(data) {
    if (data) {
      document.querySelector('**formSelector**').submit()
    } else {
      // notify user
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Right  now though, it seems that the username returns undefined every time. Do I need to use another method?

Comment: undefined where...in back end of what is being sent?

Comment: Oh...`getElementsByName` returns a collection. try `document.getElementsByName("username")[0]`

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I can figure out the rest now :D